# Please add a corresponding hat for casting downvotes

Tags: discussion, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

People will hunt for the gem watcher hat and this will lead to a decreased quality of questions. To offset this, please add hats for casting downvotes on questions that stay closed or deleted after 4 days. This is especially a problem on Stack Overflow.

Comment: In hindsight, it would probably be very easy to get hats for downvotes, probably much easier than for upvotes. I haven't cast any upvote today yet.

Comment: I merciless upvote meta posts

Answer (score 17):

The trigger for the "[I voted](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/i-voted)" hat has now been updated. The hat is now being awarded for both *upvotes* **and** *downvotes* (on open questions/answers).

[image: Pic of the 'I voted' hat on the WB mini-site, with the description: "Upvote or downvote on any open question or answer."]

Comment: Excellent! That's what it should have been all along. Thank you!

Comment: now if only we had one for downvoting 50 questions that get closed