# Is the trigger broken for the I Voted hat?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

The description of the [I Voted](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/i-voted) hat claims that it requires a user voting on question or answer. The description seems to be incorrect, I have done the following actions:

- Downvote
- Close vote
- Delete vote

These actions are from at least one hours ago. It seems either the hat is being awarded less often than this or the description is wrong because two types of voting are not counted as "voting".

Comment: It seems that it needs to be an upvote (so the description is incorrect), but I may be wrong

Comment: Just got the hat for upvoting, so can confirm. Went hunting for a post to downvote or close - sigh, once again, DV's and CV's are discriminated against :)

Comment: @RafaelTavares I do suspect it is indeed an "upvote" that counts as a "vote". This is still a bug. Either the description has to be fixed or the trigger. It's wrong in either case.

Comment: nope, no hat on a downvote (I swear the post deserved it) - sigh

Comment: [related note](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/132350?m=59887758#59887758) from Catija in the WB chat

Comment: i mean, i have the hat on SO, and i haven't cast an upvote today, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Similar story here on SE.

Comment: @KevinB I've not cast upvotes but I don't have it. I've cast 2 downvotes, 1 deletion vote, 8 close votes.

Comment: @VLAZ SEDE might actually help us - what else is counted as votes?

Comment: @OlegValter according to the votes tab in the profile, it's upvote, downvote, deletion, undeletion, close, reopen.

Comment: I have cast other kinds of votes, i assumed i got it from a downvote. Alternative would be a closevote

Comment: @KevinB downvote is confirmed to not award the hat. Did not test a close vote, though. Even tested bookmarking and will try edit suggestion approval (if I find at least *one* worthy of it) as SEDE lists them in VoteTypes table

Comment: i did cast a comment upvote on mse, that and downvote are the only two vote types i've used on mse today

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We've updated the description for the I voted hat to specify that it requires upvoting a post and the long description makes it clear that it's a question or answer, not comments.

Thanks Yaakov!

Comment: Thanks, I guess? Still do not understand why upvotes that are already heavily skewered towards must get a hat (and thus increase in numbers, let's not underestimate the hat hunt), whereas the curation actions should not.

Comment: I hear what you're saying... I guess I'm thinking that the hat awarded for a week of voting (up or down) is more likely to increase voting and it does include downvotes. I kinda think we're just fine as is.

Comment: ...and scrap the above as per [Yaakov's message in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59897634#59897634) - thank you for listening for feedback, even if it is not always pleasant to hear - that is highly appreciated!

Comment: As noted above, a relevant update from [Yaakov's answer to "Please add a corresponding hat for casting downvotes"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374089/335251): "The trigger for the "I voted" hat has now been updated. The hat is now being awarded for both upvotes and downvotes (on open questions/answers)."

Comment: Just for the record - removed the initial comment before I learned of the change - since both types of votes now count, it is obsolete (and it is very nice to see that the company and the community can cooperate rather than antagonise each other)